# parsing nested XML in android

Tags: android

I am unable to parse nested XML. It has nested node, each node having attributes and child

```
    <navigation-bar title = "" color = "#7eb432" backButtonTitle = "Back">
        <!--<navigation-item type = "1" action = "" />-->
    </navigation-bar>

    <tab-bar numberOfTabs = "4" >
        <tab-bar-item title = "Home" image = "tab_home.png" linkedScreen = "101" />
        <tab-bar-item title = "Calendar" image = "tab_calendar.png" linkedScreen = "102" />
        <tab-bar-item title = "Menu" image = "tab_menu.png" linkedScreen = "604" />
        <tab-bar-item title = "Directions" image = "tab_directions.png" linkedScreen = "401" />
        <tab-bar-item title = "Contact" image = "tab_contact.png" linkedScreen = "206" />
    </tab-bar>

</screen>

<screen id = "101" backgroundColor = "" backgroundImg = "HomeScreenBg.png" templateId = "11" hasNavigationBar = "0" hasTabBar = "1" 
cresInfoButton = "1" >

    <navigation-bar title = "" color = "#7eb432" backButtonTitle = "Back">
        <!--<navigation-item type = "1" action = "" />-->
    </navigation-bar>
    <button-view yOffset = "100" spacing = "6" />
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "blue_home_button.png" action = "201" textColor = "#ffffff">About The Clifton School</button>
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "blue_home_button.png" action = "102" textColor = "#ffffff">School Calendar</button>
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "blue_home_button.png" action = "103" textColor = "#ffffff">Admissions</button>
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "red_home_button.png" action = "601" textColor = "#ffffff">Parent Corner</button>
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "green_home_button.png.png" action = "301" textColor = "#ffffff">Request Information</button>
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "green_home_button.png.png" action = "401" textColor = "#ffffff">Directions</button>
    <button width = "274" height = "30" image = "green_home_button.png.png" action = "112" textColor = "#ffffff">Tell a Friend about Clifton</button>

</screen>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are aware of this SAX parser the confusion you are getting is in parsing those node which are getting repeated. Right ? And the problem is where to store each record while parsing. Well use startElement() and endElement() method and you can use ArrayList of any kind of objects for nested elements.

Comment: ok sir but I make only one pojo class or more than one please guide me properly i am very tired....

Comment: Buddy I studied your xml resonse you will need 3 classes to represent mp3,lrc and last for id,mp3 and lrc;

Answer (score 1):

Best way to parse XML in Android is using SAX parser. Android has this library defined in its SDK. You can go through the tutorials:
[SAXParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html)

You can get examples here:
[Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example) 
[android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser/) 
[android-sax-parsing-example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-sax-parsing-example/)

If you have any issues/problems while parsing you can post here. Parsing nested xml is not an issue, since SAX parsers are event based, you have to read the nested tags in startElement()  of overridden DefaultHandler class.

Comment: please clear only one thing how many pojo classes should be created here and how set its properties..

Answer (score 0):

you can set a flag in the father node like this:

```
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String temp=new String(ch,start,length);

        if (tagName.equals("id")){
            mp3Info.setId(temp);

        }

        else if(tagName.equals("mp3")){
            flag=1;
//          System.out.println( temp);
//          
//          mp3Info.setMp3Name(temp);
        }
        else if (tagName.equals("name") && flag==1){
            mp3Info.setMp3Name(temp);
        }
        else if (tagName.equals("size") && flag==1){
            mp3Info.setMp3Size(temp);
        }
        else if(tagName.equals("lrc")){
            flag=2;
        }
        else if(tagName.equals("name")&& flag==2){
            mp3Info.setLrcName(temp);
        }
        else if(tagName.equals("size") && flag==2){
            mp3Info.setLrcSize(temp);
        }
    }
```

the xml is:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <id>0001</id>
        <mp3>
            <name>Baby</name>
            <size>8586816</size>
        </mp3>
        <lrc>
            <name>Baby.lrc</name>
            <size>2385</size>
        </lrc>      
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <id>0002</id>
        <mp3>
            <name>Beat It.mp3</name>
            <size>7259782</size>
        </mp3>
        <lrc>
            <name>Beat It.lrc</name>
            <size>2536</size>
        </lrc>      


</resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: please clear structure of startElement & EndElement please guide me more...And In my case how much pojo classes should be made? please help me